# local ip port not available at public ip

Tags: centos, iptables, port-forwarding

I have server with centos 7.2. At locally a process is running at `127.0.0.1:8080` and it's working successfully as i use it `curl -i http://localhost:8080` then it get proper html response however when i run via public ip it is not responding at that port.

Tried via ip tables and opened that port but still not working. Also all other ports are availble as i run any nodejs server at any other port that working properly like 8090 or 9090 and so on. but why this service is not available via public ip.

Comment: Does it work locally using the public IP? Try to listen that process on 0.0.0.0:8080. Or try to forward traffic to localhost `sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.route_localnet=1`

Comment: Why do not make application to listen on public IP also?

Comment: @RomeoNinov I don't know how to edit source code https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc

Comment: See my answer for the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per discussion to make your app to listen to other than localhost you can edit file:

```
apprtc/src/third_party/oauth2client/tools.py
```

And edit line to point your public IP

```
argparser.add_argument('--auth_host_name', default='localhost',
```

to become

```
argparser.add_argument('--auth_host_name', default='Public_IP',
```

Comment: awsome. that also helped me to figure out if ../google-cloud-sdk/bin/dev_appserver.py --host <public_ip> out/app_engine/. thanks for that as nothing was mentioned in document